# Unable to render an aura component using "lightning:container" in a visual force page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

i am trying to use an aura component using `lightning:container` (which renders a static resource react app), in a visual force page.

for that i have created a `classicAppDep.app` with this code -

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
  <aura:dependency resource="lightning:container" />
</aura:application>
```

and then i use this in the visual force page as -

```
<apex:page standardController="Case"  html-width="100%" html-height="100%"  sidebar="false" showheader="false"
           standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" id="myPage">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("xyz:classicAppDep", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("xyz:app",
              {},
              "lightning",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("app rendered");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

where `xyz:app` is my aura component which uses `lightning:container` to render a static resource react app.

But when i am adding this visualforce page to my page, i am getting this error in my console-

**Refused to display 'https://mydomain.container.lightning.com/lcc/1569347477000/reactApp/index.html?sflocale=en_US' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://mydomain.visualforce.com"**

Basically some mismatch in the domain of my static resource and that of the visualforce page.

How can i resolve this, so that the static resource (react app) renders on the visual force page? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you use `lightning:container` is because a library is not allowed to modify DOM directly in lightning. However there is no such restriction in visualforce. So you can directly load that application in visualforce.

Comment: How do i run the react app (in static resources) in visualforce?

Comment: Copy paste html in vfp. Refer to js file using script.